# Exception mapping @ManyToOne relationship in Play Framework 2.3.3 using Ebean

Tags: java, jpa, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm having trouble mapping a relationship because to models in Play Framework 2.3.3.

I have two models **GaDataModel** and **BusinessAccounts** with a relationship *ManyToOne*, in model **GaDataModel** I'm declaring the relationship inside a class **GaDataModelPK** that basically is an @Embedabble PK.

The following classes are my current implementation.

**GaDataModelPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class GaDataModelPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    public BusinessAccount businessAccount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String date;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**GaDataModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ga_data_model")
public class GaDataModel extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public GaDataModelPK gaDataModelPK;
        ...
    }
}
```

**BusinessAccounts**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_account")
public class BusinessAccount extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public BusinessAccountPK businessAccountPK;

    public String portal;

    public String region;
    public String category;

    public String hqCountry;
    public String portalCountry;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "business_account", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public List<GaDataModel> gaDataModels;

    ...
}
```

But when I try to run the application, I have the following exception

Stack Trace in PLAY WEBBROWSER

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for repository.models.GaDataModelPK
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:54)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1028)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createEmbedded(BeanDescriptorManager.java:455)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEmbeddedDeployment(BeanDescriptorManager.java:478)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:232)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:114)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:204)
     com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:65)
     com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:58)
     play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:89)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
     play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:105)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
```

Stack Trace in PLAY CONSOLE:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSPlugin.onStop(NingWSPlugin.java:31) ~[play-java-ws_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(Play.scala:108) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(Play.scala:107) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:107) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/analytics
[error] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for repository.models.GaDataModelPK
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1028) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createEmbedded(BeanDescriptorManager.java:455) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEmbeddedDeployment(BeanDescriptorManager.java:478) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:232) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class repository.models.BusinessAccount] from [repository.models.GaDataModelPK.businessAccount]. Is class repository.models.BusinessAccount registered?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readManyToOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:165) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readAssocOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:63) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.parse(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:45) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1028) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
[error] application - 

! @6j99d9gfb - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for repository.models.GaDataModelPK]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:151) ~[play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115) ~[play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:115) ~[play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:113) ~[play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for repository.models.GaDataModelPK
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1028) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createEmbedded(BeanDescriptorManager.java:455) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEmbeddedDeployment(BeanDescriptorManager.java:478) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:232) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class repository.models.BusinessAccount] from [repository.models.GaDataModelPK.businessAccount]. Is class repository.models.BusinessAccount registered?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readManyToOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:165) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readAssocOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:63) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.parse(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:54) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:45) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1028) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contact", targetEntity= gaDataModels.class)
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="business_account", nullable=false)
```

That was with Play 2.1.1, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Do you declare the relationship inside the @Embeddable class?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to:

1. Move @ManyToOne relation from GaDataModelPK to GaDataModel then add attributes 'insertable'=false and 'updateable'=false to @JoinColumn annotation.
2. In GaDataModelPK class leave businessAccountId.
3. Override setter for businessAccount in GaDataModel. In this setter we should write businessAccount.id to composite key.

Here is the code:

GaDataModel class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ga_data_model")
public class GaDataModel extends Model {

    public GaDataModel(String aDate) {
        gaDataModelPK = new GaDataModelPK();
        gaDataModelPK.date = aDate;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public GaDataModelPK gaDataModelPK;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_account_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private BusinessAccount businessAccount;

    public void setBusinessAccount(BusinessAccount aBusinessAccount) {
        businessAccount = aBusinessAccount;
        gaDataModelPK.businessAccountId = aBusinessAccount.id;
    }
}
```

GaDataModelPK class:

```
@Embeddable
public class GaDataModelPK implements Serializable {

    public Long businessAccountId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String date;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return businessAccountId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

BusinessAccount class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_account")
public class BusinessAccount extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String portal;
    public String region;
    public String category;
    public String hqCountry;
    public String portalCountry;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessAccount")
    public List<GaDataModel> gaDataModels;
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
public void businessAccountTest () {
    FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());
    Helpers.start(app);

    BusinessAccount ba = new BusinessAccount();
    ba.id=1L;

    GaDataModel gd = new GaDataModel("01/01/2014");
    gd.setBusinessAccount(ba);
    ba.gaDataModels.add(gd);

    Ebean.save(ba);
    Ebean.save(gd);

    BusinessAccount fba = Ebean.find(BusinessAccount.class, 1L);
    GaDataModel fgd = fba.gaDataModels.get(0);
    System.out.println("GaDataModel:  date:"+fgd.gaDataModelPK.date);
}
```

NOTE: You didn't provide code of BusinessAccountPK class in your post so I changed id of BusinessAccount to Long. 
But you can make this relation the same way as GaDataModel - GaDataModelPK relation. Or I can update my answer if you update your question.